# How to check radio button based on intent string

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button, findviewbyid

I'm trying to check a radio button based upon an value derived from an intent sent from the previous activity. Upon screen load, the radioButton.getText().toString() should compare against a specific value and check that particular radio button if it evaluates to true but I am not getting the expected results.

I've looked on stack overflow and various documentation/tutorial sites but I haven't came across anyone else having this particular issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction of solving this issue?
Here's the relevant activity code :

```
courseStatus = getIntent().getStringExtra("course_status");
editCourseStatusG = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
editStatusComplete = findViewById(R.id.editStatusCompleted);
editStatusDropped = findViewById(R.id.editStatusDropped);
editStatusOngoing = findViewById(R.id.editStatusOngoing);
editStatusPlanned = findViewById(R.id.editStatusPlanned);

    
if(courseStatus.equals(editStatusComplete.getText().toString())) {
        editStatusComplete.setChecked(true);
} else if (courseStatus.equals(editStatusDropped.getText().toString())) {
        editStatusDropped.setChecked(true);
} else if ((courseStatus.equals(editStatusOngoing.getText().toString()))) {
        editStatusOngoing.setChecked(true);
} else if ((courseStatus.equals(editStatusPlanned.getText().toString()))) {
        editStatusPlanned.setChecked(true);
}
```

XML code:

```
<RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/editStatusOngoing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="Ongoing"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/editStatusCompleted"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Completed"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/editStatusDropped"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="Dropped"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/editStatusPlanned"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="Planned"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some troubleshooting, I still cannot find the answer to the issue at hand. The getText() method is not evaluating correctly to the given string. However, a work around it to compare directly the intent directly to a static string variable with the same text as the radioButton.getText() method should return.

Working code:

```
       editCourseStatusG = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
       editStatusComplete = findViewById(R.id.editStatusCompleted);
       editStatusDropped = findViewById(R.id.editStatusDropped);
       editStatusOngoing = findViewById(R.id.editStatusOngoing);
       editStatusPlanned = findViewById(R.id.editStatusPlanned);

       try {
           switch (courseStatus) {
               case "Completed":
                   editStatusComplete.setChecked(true);
                   break;
               case "Dropped":
                   editStatusDropped.setChecked(true);
                   break;
               case "Ongoing":
                   editStatusOngoing.setChecked(true);
                   break;
               case "Planned":
                   editStatusPlanned.setChecked(true);
                   break;
               default:
                   editStatusPlanned.setChecked(true);
           }
       } catch(NullPointerException e) {
           editStatusPlanned.setChecked(true);
       }
```

Comment: Enum status is better than String.

Comment: ```editStatusComplete.setChecked(courseStatus == MyStatus.Completed);```